# Showing a list of images using PHP

Tags: php, image

I have got a directory which contains several folders with images. What I want to do is to read all the images using php script and showing them with div in a browser. The code I have tried to implement is the following:

```
<?php

function listFolderFiles($dir) 
{
    echo '<ol>';
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $folder) {
        if (!$folder->isDot()) {
            // echo '<li>' . $folder->getFilename() . '<br>';
            if ($folder->isDir()) {
                $user = $dir . '/' . $folder;
                foreach (new DirectoryIterator($user) as $file) {
                    if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                        // echo '<li>' . $file->getFilename();
                        $image = $user . '/' . $file;

                        echo $image . '<br>'; 

                        echo '<div>';
                        echo '<img src="' . $image . '" width="500" height="500" alt="'; 
                        echo '"/>';
                        echo '</div>';
                    }
                }
            }
            echo '</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ol>';
}

listFolderFiles('images');
```

The command `echo $image.'<br>';` prints the names of all images. With the following command I manage to create div, however without the images been displayed inside them:

```
echo '<div>';
echo '<img src="' . $image . '" width="500" height="500" alt="';
echo '"/>';
echo '</div>';
```

Am I doing something wrong? The $image paths are correct. 
EDIT: I move the folder of images in the same folder with the php file in the wamp folder. Now for example the image file is the following images/01virarias/1_.jpg.  I change the call of my function as listFolderFiles('images');. However I am getting the same empty divs.

Comment: what is `echo '"/>';` at the end

Comment: Ok it is not necessary, however I think it is not wrong. Either I tried  echo '<img src="'. $image .'" width="500" height="500" alt=/>'; I have the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an URL. It seems you are using local files. Your browser is the 'problem'. Although it is a matter of security.

The images should be in your server environment.

And it seems you forgot a `<li>` start tag.

Comment: Yes I am using local files from hard disk. I have to convert $image to url?

Comment: Your code is fine, you just need to test it online with images that are online as well.

Comment: My code is inside wamp server. Wamp server is online. I am running it in localhost.

Comment: Am I  suppose to place all my images in wamp folder?

Answer (score 1):

if your path is correct do a inspect element on your browser i think it's quoting issue try

```
echo '<img src="'. $image .'" width="500" height="500" alt=""/>';
```

You can use images path relative/absolute like

```
relative :- ../images/your_image
absolute :-  http://localhost/your_image_path
```

Comment: I got the same empty divs.

Comment: Yes, in firebug it shows every div and its my actual paths:<div><img src="D:/images/0utofReach7/14_.jpg" width="500" height="500" alt=""><\div>

Comment: Maybe some of the images are corrupted. Is there a chance that this issue affect all divs?

Comment: you can also use absolute/relative path of images, or `http://localhost/your_image path`

Comment: As I said in EDIT in main post I edit the call of my function to listFolderFiles('images'); and I put image folder in the same folder with php script in wamp folder. However I got the same empty div. If I change the path to something else I got errors.